# fread() returns incorrect data

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, fread

I am trying to read 128KB binary file in chunks of 256 Bytes. The first 20-40 bytes of 256 bytes seems to be always correct. However after that the data gets corrupted. I tried reading the file and writing it into another binary file and compared. More than half of the data is corrupted. Here is my code

```
uint8_t buffer[256]
read_bin_file = fopen("vtest.bin", "r");
if (read_bin_file == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to open file\n");
    return false;
}

test_bin = fopen("test_file.bin", "w");
if (test_file == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to open file\n");
    return false;
}

fflush(stdout);

for (i = 0; i <=0x1FF; i++)
{
    file_Read_pointer = i * 256;
    fseek(read_bin_file, file_Read_pointer, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buffer, 256, 1, read_bin_file);
    fseek(test_file, file_Read_pointer, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(buffer, 256, 1, test_file);

}
```

What is that I am missing?
Also when i try to increase the bytes read from 256 to 1024 ( i<0x7F) the error seems to decrease significantly. The file is almost 90% matching

Answer (score 4):

If it is binary data you're reading and writing, then you should open the files in binary mode with `read_bin_file = fopen("vtest.bin", "rb");`. Note the "b" in the mode. This prevents special handling of new line characters.

Your `fseek`s are also unnecessary, the `fread` and `fwrite` calls will handle that for you.
From [here](http:///http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fread) "The file position indicator for the stream is advanced by the number of characters read."

Comment: Changing from "r" to "rb" helped.However there are some bytes still mismatched. The reason I use Fseek is I might have to read from random location..

Comment: @user3869908 if you want to start reading at a random location, a single `fseek` before starting your read loop is enough.

Comment: @user3869908 fread returns a size_t to say how much it has read, this should match what you ask for if the data is there to be read, but may not if an error occurred, the same with fwrite. It is worth checking these values to ensure everything has happened as expected.

Comment: @user3869908 just to check, you've changed the "w" to "wb" for your output file too?